# Как создать исполняемое приложение Java?

Tags: java, компиляция, exe, jvm

Я новичок в Java и я внезапно поймал себя на том, что не знаю, как создать приложение, которое можно будет запускать без среды разработки.

Например, я написал свой калькулятор из нескольких классов с GUI, и теперь хочу получить его в виде самостоятельного приложения, которое можно будет запустить на любом компьютере с предустановленной JRE. Как это можно осуществить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно собрать классы в jar файл c помощью сборщика пакетов. Рекомендую ознакомиться с [maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/)

Comment: А если, допустим, в программе будет файл .properties и я должен буду иметь возможность изменить что-то в нём, то как я вытащу его из jar-файла? Или после сборки он будет идти отдельно?

Comment: Придётся создавать контроллер который будет изменять проперти и использовать его через программу

Comment: Jar файл запускается как обычная программа? Т.е. я просто тапну два раза по нему и программа запустится? Опять же, в мавене ведь есть возможность указать исполняющий класс, который запускается при запуске программы?

Comment: Нет, не как обычная программа. Да, есть

Answer (score 0):

Если без сборщиков проектов можно через IDE создать исполняемый файл и запускать его (ссылка на видео как это сделать https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tA8rEz_xFrQ)
Либо через какой либо сборщик пакетов Maven или Gradle

Comment: Опишите процесс в самом ответе, а не по ссылке